# User controls, web parts and WSPBuilder

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, user-controls, web-parts, wspbuilder

Can anyone point me to tutorials on how to use WSPBuilder to host a user control in a MOSS webpart?

Answer (score 4):

With WSPBuilder, create a "Web Part Feature" within your solution; and then follow along with this tutorial:

http://jcapka.blogspot.com/2009/01/i-was-explaining-my-technique-of-using.html

The only thing you'll to do to get everything packaged nicely in WSPBuilder's generated WSP would be to add your usercontrol to the following folder in your solution:

12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES

(you'll need to "add folder" within VS to get the "CONTROLTEMPLATES" folder; "TEMPLATE" should already be present, with the "FEATURES" folder under it)

Have WSPBuilder build the solution for you, and then deploy!